# Search an element and take action

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Guess you all are doing good!!

I have a scenario where I need to do the following:

I have an xml withe content as below.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <key>One</key>
            <value>Value1</value>
        </c>
        <c>
            <key>Two</key>
            <value>Value2</value>
        </c>
        <c>
            <key>Three</key>
            <value>Value3</value>
        </c>
        <c>
            <key>Four</key>
            <value>Value4</value>
        </c>
        <c>
            <key>Five</key>
            <value>Value5</value>
        </c>
    </b>
   <d>
       <e>
            <Five>Check this feild</Five>
            <Seven>It is extra</Seven>
            <tewnty>extra</tewnty>
        </e>
        <f>
            <Three>it is present</Three>
            <Five>Came again</Five>
        </f>
        <g>
            <Four>It is here</Four>
        </g>
    </d>
    <n>
        <Five>Dont check under n</Five>
        <Six>Extra under n</Six>
        <Three>Dont check under n</Three>
    </n>
</a>`
```

Now I want check if     `/a/b/c/key/text()` exists as an element name 
    `/a/d`

If true, then copy the current key/value pair.
If not ignore this key/value pair to output.

So my output should look like:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <key>Three</key>
            <value>Value3</value>
        </c>
        <c>
            <key>Four</key>
            <value>Value4</value>
        </c>
        <c>
            <key>Five</key>
            <value>Value5</value>
        </c>
    </b>
    <d>
        <e>
            <Five>Check this feild</Five>
            <Seven>It is extra</Seven>
            <tewnty>extra</tewnty>
        </e>
        <f>
            <Three>it is present</Three>
            <Five>Came again</Five>
        </f>
        <g>
            <Four>It is here</Four>
        </g>
    </d>
    <n>
        <Five>Dont check under n</Five>
        <Six>Extra under n</Six>
        <Three>Dont check under n</Three>
    </n>
</a>`
```

Can you please help me with the     XSLT.

I was trying with if and checking with `local-name()` of node.

how can I achieve it in     XSLT?

My quesion, how can I remove a node (in my case somevaluesomevalue) based on element name = (c/key/text()).

I hope my question is specific.

Thanks & Regards
Chandru

Comment: Please read [**Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/290085)

Answer (score 1):

The following stylesheet uses an [`xsl:key`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) for the elements under `/a/d/*/*` using their `local-name()` and then use that as criteria to exclude elements under `/a/b/*` who's `text()` value does not find any items in the `xsl:key`.

This is a modified [identity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) where default processing is to preserve everything. The elements that match the second empty template that uses the `xsl:key` ensure that those elements will be removed.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" />

  <xsl:key name="filter" match="/a/d/*/*" use="local-name()"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/a/b/c[not(key('filter', key/text()))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Mads for the reply. I tried this. It is generating the input as output.

Comment: @user2071463, at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhe (XSLT 3 version) and http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhe/1 (XSLT 2 version) you can see that Mads approach with the key works.